# When a class provides overloads for a parameter of subclass and superclass types, which gets priority?

Tags: java

```
class Callback{
    public void notify(A arg){ ...}
    public void notify(B arg){ ...}

    private static class B extends A { ...}

    public A create() { return new B(...); }
}

Callback callback = new Callback();

A a = new A(...);
A b = callback.create();

callback.notify(a);
callback.notify(b);
```

I find the `A` overload is called both times in this scenario even though in the debugger it knows `a` is of type `B`. Is this what is supposed to happen or has the inner class screwed things up somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, the method signature called is determined at compile time, not at runtime. Java determined which method to call based on the statically determined type of the argument, not its actual type at run time. Both `a` and `b` are references of `A` type , hence both the times `public void notify(A arg)` is called. Refer [Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) for more.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to happen - what you're thinking of is [multimethod dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), which is supported by a few other languages but not by Java.  Multimethods usually either require a linear time method lookup at runtime, or else they require a very complex algorithm for creating the dispatch table; instead of either of these, Java always uses the declared type and not the actual type for parameter matching, which is a lot simpler to implement and doesn't incur any additional runtime cost above and beyond that of dynamic dispatch.